# OKTA application deactivate returns 404

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

I am trying to create and then immediately deactivate an OKTA application using a c# code with the OKTA API.

I am able to successfully create the application and extract the client id, but when trying to deactivate the app, I get an error that the client was not found.

This is how I try to deactivate:

```
 public async static Task<bool> DeactivateApp(string accessToken, string clientId)
    {
        string oktaDomain = "https://myDomain.okta.com";
        string requestUrl = $"{oktaDomain}/api/v1/apps/${clientId}/lifecycle/deactivate";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string token = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, null); //here i get the 404 response

        ...
    }
```

The client id is correct and I can see that an app does exist with that client id.

What could be the cause of that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the url.

```
string requestUrl = $"{oktaDomain}/api/v1/apps/${clientId}/lifecycle/deactivate";
```

I accidentally added $ before the `clientId` in the middle thus creating a wrong url. It searched an id with a $ at the start which of course didn't exist. Once removed, it worked as it should

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in your code is that the token which is to be sent in "Authorization" header needs to "SSWS <token_value>", Kindly check. Rest everything looks fine.

Comment: Oauth bearer tokens are also valid for use. I have added an answer to my (dumb) mistake